# Docker Postgres file illegal option -

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to put variables inside my CMD of a Dockerfile that has a Postgres container with certificates needed for SSL. I am using this Dockerfile as build context from a docker-compose.yml file that this database as one service and an app

**db.Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres:14.5-alpine

ENV EXT_KEY .key

COPY ./.docker/dev/init-database.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

COPY ./.docker/dev/migrations/database_schema.tar ./

COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/postgresdb$EXT_KEY /var/lib/postgresql
COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/postgresdb.crt /var/lib/postgresql

COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/myCA.crt /var/lib/postgresql
COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/myCA.crl /var/lib/postgresql

COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/news_user$EXT_KEY ./
COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/news_user.crt ./

RUN chown 0:70 /var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb$EXT_KEY && chmod 640 /var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb$EXT_KEY
RUN chown 0:70 /var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.crt && chmod 640 /var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.crt

RUN chown 0:70 /var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt && chmod 640 /var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt
RUN chown 0:70 /var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl && chmod 640 /var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl

RUN chown 0:70 ./news_user$EXT_KEY && chmod 640 ./news_user$EXT_KEY
RUN chown 0:70 ./news_user.crt && chmod 640 ./news_user.crt

RUN chown postgres:postgres /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sh

EXPOSE 5432

USER postgres

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"] 

CMD [ "-c", "ssl=on" , "-c", "ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.crt", "-c",\
    "ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.${EXT_KEY}", "-c",\
    "ssl_ca_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt", "-c", "ssl_crl_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  news_database:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./.docker/dev/db.Dockerfile
    container_name: news_database
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - news_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  news_app:
    ...

volumes:
  news_db:
    driver: local
```

When I run this the variable is not present in the CMD and therefore the container fails

**Attempt 1**

I tried changing the final command from array to string format

```
CMD -c ssl=on -c ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.crt -c ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.key -c ssl_ca_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt -c ssl_crl_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl
```

It gives me an /bin/sh: illegal option - error

**Attempt 2**

I removed the entrypoint completely and tried directly calling postgres with a CMD

```
CMD postgres -c ssl=on -c ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.crt -c ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.key -c ssl_ca_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt -c ssl_crl_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl
```

It immediately gives me another error when I run it via docker-compose

```
postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

All I want is to have variables inside that CMD, can someone kindly tell me a way to make this work?

Comment: "When I run this the variable is not present in the CMD"  *What* variable is not present?

Comment: @jjanes the value for EXT_KEY inside CMD, i want to basically put all my crt file names inside variables and then have cmd substitute it

Comment: Shouldn't this line `ENV EXT_KEY .key` be like `ENV EXT_KEY=key`?

Comment: @qaziqarta still doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure you need to parametrize the command line like this? It's going to needlessly complicate things and it doesn't seem to get you any additional functionality. You can just use fixed paths in the command line, and then replace them using bind mounts when you start the container. This will be even easier if you move your certificates out of `/var/lib/postgresql` and into a dedicated certificate directory (because then you can just mount a new directory at that location, replacing everything at once).

Answer (score -1):

Your `ENTRYPOINT` instruction is specified as JSON array, meaning it's in [exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) form - no shell will be invoked for the execution of `docker-entrypoint.sh`. As there is no shell invoked, there won't be any environment variable expansion.

To make it work, try this:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", \
"docker-entrypoint.sh \
-c ssl=on \
-c ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.crt \
-c ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb${EXT_KEY} \
-c ssl_ca_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt \
-c ssl_crl_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl \
${0} ${@}" ]
```

Comment: exits with code 0 if you do this, it doesnt even show the reason https://imgur.com/a/MqYLCvH

Comment: Fixed - it turns out that the command to "sh -c" must be passed in full.

Comment: postgres: invalid argument: "sh" :(

Comment: @PirateApp, can you post the full output from the command, with which you run the container, and which gives you this error?